# Importing index.ts by only using the directory

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to import a module index.ts from a directory without specifying the module name itself but rather only only the directory name and this results in a `TS2307: Cannot find module` error.

./src/main.ts:

```
'use strict';

// success
import {helloWorld as helloWorld1} from '../lib/helloworld/index';

// failure
import {helloWorld as helloWorld3} from '../lib/helloworld';

helloWorld1();
```

./lib/helloworld/index.ts:

```
'use strict';

export function helloWorld() {
    console.log('Hello World');
}
```

This works as expected when using native JavaScript but fails in TypeScript.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using Node path resolution strategy.

In your `tsconfig.json`, set your `compilerOptions.moduleResolution` to `"node"`.